# Loop em pl/sql oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, pl-sql, oracle11g

Quero saber como percorrer todas as tuplas que estão armazenadas em uma tabela; como faço isso em **PL/SQL Oracle**?

Desde já, grato!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entendo que você queira usar um **cursor**. Em `PL/SQL` você pode fazer usando `FOR`.
Suponha que você tenha uma tabela com os campos Codigo e Nome, um exemplo seria assim:

```
FOR i IN (SELECT Codigo, Nome FROM Tabela)
LOOP
    /*Aqui é possível ler cada campo da tupla usando a variável "i"*/
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.Codigo||' '||i.Nome);
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar cursores de duas maneiras:

**Cursor explícito**:

```
DECLARE
  --
  CURSOR cr_produto(pr_categoria IN produtos.id_categoria%TYPE) IS
    SELECT produto, preco
      FROM produtos
     WHERE (id_categoria = pr_categoria OR pr_categoria = 0)
     ORDER BY preco DESC;
  rw_produto cr_produto%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  FOR rw_produto IN cr_produto(pr_categoria => 0) LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line( rw_produto.nome || ': $' ||  rw_produto.preco );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Neste exemplo, o `SELECT` do cursor recupera dados da tabela produtos. A instrução `FOR LOOP` foi aberta, buscou cada linha no conjunto de resultados, exibiu as informações do produto e fechou o cursor.

O exemplo a seguir é equivalente ao exemplo acima, chamado de **cursor implícito**, mas usa uma consulta interna na instrução `FOR LOOP`.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    vr_categoria produtos.id_categoria%TYPE;
  BEGIN

    vr_categoria := 0;

    FOR rw_produto IN (
          SELECT produto, preco
            FROM produtos
           WHERE (id_categoria = vr_categoria OR vr_categoria = 0)
           ORDER BY preco DESC
      )
    LOOP
       dbms_output.put_line( rw_produto.nome || ': $' ||  rw_produto.preco );
    END LOOP;
  END;
END;
```

Como pode imaginar, ambos tem suas vantagens e desvantagens, no caso do cursor explícito, você pode fazer uso em diversas situações ao longo da package, procedure ou function, sem precisar montar um select a cada loop do seu programa. Em contrapartida, em rotinas simples, onde o mesmo cursor não será usado mais de uma vez, pode usar a forma implícita.